# Python loop through specific JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file:

```
[
{
    "db_name":1,
    "daily" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [1,3,29],
               "delete_after" : 14,              
             }
},
{
    "db_name":2,
    "daily" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [1,3,29],
               "delete_after" : 14,
              }

}
]
```

I have an input from user for the requested db_name and then for this specific db_name I want to loop through the array "days_to_backup". my code right now:

```
import argparse
import json
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#-db DATABSE -t TYPE  -p PROCESSS
parser.add_argument("-p", "--process", help="Process")
parser.add_argument("-db", "--database", help="Database name")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--type", help="Backup type")



args = parser.parse_args()

print( "Process:{} Database:{} Type:{}   ".format(
        args.process,
        args.database,
        args.type,


        ))


with open('C:/Users/llll/Desktop/f.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)


if  args.process == 'backup':
        print("Asked for backup")
        for keyval in data:
          if args.database == keyval['db_name']:
                print(args.database)
                print("Database exist")
                ## checked if the DB inserted exists, now i want here to loop through the array days_to_backup
                sys.exit()

        print("Database doesn't exist")

else:
        print("Currently support only backups")
```

How do I specify to loop through specific object of the JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
db_lst = [
    {
        "db_name": 1,
        "daily": {
            "days_to_backup": [1, 3, 29],
            "delete_after": 14,
        }
    },
    {
        "db_name": 2,
        "daily": {
            "days_to_backup": [1, 3, 29],
            "delete_after": 14,
        }

    }
]
db_name = 1
for entry in db_lst:
    if entry.get("db_name") == db_name:
        for day in entry["daily"]["days_to_backup"]:
            print(day)
```

output

```
1
3
29
```